# Issues with Subnets in my secondary instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Please have some grace because I just started learning AWS. I am trying to launch a PostgreSQL DB from Terraform and I keep running into this subnet error

```
Error: error creating RDS cluster: DBSubnetGroupNotFoundFault: DB subnet group 'cse-cr' does not exist.
│   status code: 404, request id: 6461e755-8118-41ee-8baf-5678e28c39aa
│ 
│   with aws_rds_cluster.secondary,
│   on maindb.tf line 67, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "secondary":
│   67: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "secondary" {
```

I tried adding a second resource section specifically for the secondary cluster/instance but that also did not work. What am I doing wrong...?

Here is my code:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "primary"
  region = "us-east-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "secondary"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_rds_global_cluster" "example" {
  global_cluster_identifier = "global-test"
  engine                    = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version            = "13.4"
  database_name             = "example_db"
}

variable "database_name" {
  description = "What should RDS name the initial db?"
  default     = "variableWithSomeDefault"
}


data "aws_subnet" "subnet1" {
  id = "subnet-numhere"
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet2" {
  id = "subnet-numhere"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name        = "cse-cr"
  description = "Private subnets for RDS instance"
  subnet_ids  = [data.aws_subnet.subnet1.id, data.aws_subnet.subnet2.id]
}


resource "aws_rds_cluster" "primary" {
  provider                  = aws.primary
  engine                    = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version            = "13.4"
  cluster_identifier        = "test-primary-cluster"
  master_username           = "username"
  master_password           = "somepass123"
  database_name             = var.database_name
  global_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_global_cluster.example.global_cluster_identifier
  db_subnet_group_name      = "cse-cr"
  skip_final_snapshot       = true
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "primary" {
  provider           = aws.primary
  engine             = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version     = "13.4"
  identifier         = "primaryinstancetest"
  cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.primary.cluster_identifier}"
  instance_class     = "db.r5.large"
  db_subnet_group_name = "cse-cr"
}



resource "aws_rds_cluster" "secondary" {
  provider                  = aws.secondary
  engine                    = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version            = "13.4"
  cluster_identifier        = "test-secondary-cluster"
  global_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_global_cluster.example.global_cluster_identifier
  skip_final_snapshot       = true
  db_subnet_group_name      = "cse-cr"
  

  depends_on = [
    aws_rds_cluster_instance.primary
  ]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "secondary" {
  provider             = aws.secondary
  engine               = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version       = "13.4"
  identifier           = "secondaryinstancetest"
  cluster_identifier   = "${aws_rds_cluster.secondary.cluster_identifier}"
  instance_class       = "db.r5.large"
  db_subnet_group_name = "cse-cr"
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, if you are creating two resources and one depends on the other, then you should always refer to the first from the second, rather than use absolute names to connect them. This becomes even more relevant when you start to use autogenerated names for resources (which is a requirement if you want to deploy the same stack multiple times in the same account) because you don't know the resource name/id in advance (it's auto-generated).

Answer (score 1):

Terraform tries to create the RDS cluster (`aws_rds_cluster.secondary`) before the DB subnet group was (`aws_db_subnet_group.default`) was provisioned. You have to have a dependency between them in order for Terraform to be able to detect the provisioning order.
To solve this, I recommend referencing the `aws_db_subnet_group.default.name` whenever it asks for the subnet group name. For example:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "primary" {
  provider           = aws.primary
  engine             = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version     = "13.4"
  identifier         = "primaryinstancetest"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.primary.cluster_identifier
  instance_class     = "db.r5.large"
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.default.name # there is no need to hardcode "cse-cr" here
}
```

Or another example in the `secondary` cluster:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "secondary" {
  provider             = aws.primary
  engine               = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version       = "13.4"
  identifier           = "secondaryinstancetest"
  cluster_identifier   = aws_rds_cluster.secondary.cluster_identifier
  instance_class       = "db.r5.large"
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_rds_cluster.primary.cluster_identifier
}
```

Please note, I removed the `secondary` provider from the second cluster. You can not have a subnet (or a VPC) which spans to 2 different regions!